# ArmA 3 LOD design for a structure?

Tags: blender, level-of-detail

I've designed and textured a house, and I now want to port it over to ArmA 3. I'm using blender to design it.[image]
When looking at tutorials, everyone seems to emphasize the LOD, which means Level of Detail. (Shown on the right) I have no clue what settings to use for a structure. The only tutorials i've seen are creating a weapon, which I'm assuming would need a low LOD since its in 1st person, but no one mentions the LOD settings of buildings, what value should I use?